# log4net RollingFileAppender filename timestamp

Tags: logging, log4net, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender

We are replacing a custom built logging component with log4Net.  Currently our log files roll based on size, but include a date/timestamp in the filename when the new log is created.

For example;
Application-2015-04-06-130733.log

when this log file reaches a configurable size, lets say 10MB, a new file is created with a fresh date/timestamp.

I have scoured the web, forums, log4net documentation, etc. and cant find a way to accomplish this in log4net config.

Here is my latest log4net config file:

```
<log4net>
    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <param name="File" type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="%property{ProgramDataLogDir}\Application-.log"/>
      <param name="AppendToFile" value="false"/>
      <param name="RollingStyle" value="Composite"/>
      <param name="DatePattern" value="yyyy-MM-dd" />
      <param name="MaxSizeRollBackups" value="-1"/>
      <param name="MaximumFileSize" value="10MB"/>
      <param name="StaticLogFileName" value="false"/>
      <param name="preserveLogFileNameExtension" value="true" />
      <threshold value="DEBUG"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%property{ThreadID} %d{MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss.fff} %property{DebugLevel} %property{ComputerName} %property{ProcessName} [%t] %c %m%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
    </root>

  </log4net>
```

This results in log files created with Application-2015-04-06.log, and when the 10MB threshold is reached a new file is created with .1, .2, .3 etc. after the date.

Application-2015-04-06.1.log

Application-2015-04-06.2.log

Application-2015-04-06.3.log

If I can change the .1, .2, .3 etc. into a datestamp HHmmss this would be perfect.

Additionally, I need to start a brand new file every time the application is started.  If I can achieve a format similar to Application-2015-04-06-130733.log it should also handle this case.

To summarize:

1.) Files roll by size.

2.) Every time a new file is created, whether its when the application starts or when rolling by size the filename should include a fresh date/timestamp.

Application-2015-04-06-130733.log

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried extending your stamp pattern to minutes and seconds, does it still create those indexes?

Comment: Yes.  It tries to create a log file every second in this case.